# Multiple columns processing and dynamically naming new columns

Tags: r, naming, data-cleaning, large-data

Variables are mistakenly being entered into multiple columns eg: "aaa_1", "aaa_2" and "aaa_3", or "ccc_1, "ccc_2", and "ccc_3"). Need to create single new columns (eg "aaa", or "ccc"). Some variables are currently in a single column though ("hhh_1"), but more columns may be added (hhh_2 etc).

This is what I got:

```
aaa_1 <- c(43, 23, 65, NA, 45)  
aaa_2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)    
aaa_3 <- c(NA, NA, 92, NA, 82)  
ccc_1 <- c("fra", NA, "spa", NA, NA)   
ccc_2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "wez", NA)  
ccc_3 <- c(NA, "ija", NA, "fda", NA)    
ccc_4 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
hhh_1 <- c(183, NA, 198, NA, 182)    
dataf1 <- data.frame(aaa_1,aaa_2,aaa_3,ccc_1,ccc_2, ccc_3,ccc_4,hhh_1)
```

This is what I want:

```
aaa <- c(43, 23, NA, NA, NA)
ccc <- c("fra", "ija", "spa", NA, NA) 
hhh <- c(183, NA, 198, NA, 182)   
dataf2 <- data.frame(aaa,ccc,hhh)
```

General solution needed as there are ~100 variables (eg "aaa", "hhh", "ccc", "ttt", "eee", "hhh"etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a base solution, i.e. no packages.

First define `get_only` which when given a list converts it to a data.frame and applies `get_only` to each row.  When given a vector it returns the single non-NA in it or NA if there is not only one.

Define `root` to be the column names without the suffixes.

Convert the data frame to a list of columns, group them by `root` and apply `get_only` to each such group.

Finally, convert the resulting list to a data frame.

```
get_only <- function(x) UseMethod("get_only")
get_only.list <- function(x) apply(data.frame(x), 1, get_only)
get_only.default <- function(x) if (sum(!is.na(x)) == 1) na.omit(x) else NA

root <- sub("_.*", "", names(dataf1))
as.data.frame(lapply(split(as.list(dataf1), root), FUN = get_only))
```

giving:

```
  age country hight
1  43     fra   183
2  23     ija    NA
3  NA     spa   198
4  NA    <NA>    NA
5  NA    <NA>   182
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so carefully!

Answer (score 0):

We may try with `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
nm1 <- sub("_\\d+", "", names(dataf1))
tbl <- table(nm1) > 1
merged.stack(dataf1, var.stubs = names(tbl)[tbl], sep="_")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your example is right. For example in the third row you've got values for both age_1 and age_3, then in the desired output NA for that row.

If I've understood what you're trying to do though, it will be much easier if you transpose columns to rows, fix them and then transpose back again. Try this as a start point using the 'tidyverse' of dplyr and tidyr.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

age_1 <- c(43, 23, 65, NA, 45)
age_2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
age_3 <- c(NA, NA, 92, NA, 82)
country_1 <- c("fra", NA, "spa", NA, NA)
country_2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "wez", NA)
country_3 <- c(NA, "ija", NA, "fda", NA)
country_4 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
hight_1 <- c(183, NA, 198, NA, 182)
dataf1 <- data.frame(age_1,age_2,age_3,country_1,country_2, country_3,country_4,hight_1)

data <- dataf1 %>%
  mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>%   #create a row number to track values
  gather(key, value, -row_num) %>%    #flatten your data
  drop_na() %>%    #drop na rows
  mutate(key = str_replace(key, "_.", "")) %>%   #remove the '_x' part of names
  group_by(row_num) %>%  
  top_n(1) %>%
  spread(key, value)  #pivot back to columns
```

For your example you need the group_by() and top_n() lines to make it run because you've got multiple values in the same row. If you only have one value (as I think you should?) then you can remove these two lines. It will be better without them because then it won't run if your data is wrong.

Edit following comment below. This will make any duplicated entries NA.

```
data <- dataf1 %>%
  mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>%   #create a row number to track values
  gather(key, value, -row_num) %>%    #flatten your data
  drop_na() %>%    #drop na rows
  mutate(key = str_replace(key, "_.", "")) %>%   #remove the '_x' part of names
  group_by(row_num, key) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%  #count how many entries for each row/key combo
  mutate(value = ifelse(count > 1, NA, value)) %>%   #set NA for rows with duplicates
  drop_na() %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%  #pivot back to columns
  select(-count)  #drop the `count` variable
```

Comment: I want to make sure that if a given person's age has been entered as both 65 (age_1) and 92 (age_3), the output is NA (as I can't be sure which of the ages is correct, I want to be able to impute that observation/row). Thanks!

Comment: Edited my answer above. You can count entries and remove any rows with duplicates